# SQL query select from table and group on other column

Tags: sql, sql-server, grouping

I'm phrasing the question title poorly as I'm not sure what to call what I'm trying to do but it really should be simple.

I've a link / join table with two ID columns. I want to run a check before saving new rows to the table.

The user can save attributes through a webpage but I need to check that the same combination doesn't exist before saving it. With one record it's easy as obviously you just check if that attributeId is already in the table, if it is don't allow them to save it again.

However, if the user chooses a combination of that attribute and another one then they should be allowed to save it.

Here's an image of what I mean:

[image]

So if a user now tried to save an attribute with ID of 1 it will stop them, but I need it to also stop them if they tried ID's of 1, 10 so long as both 1 and 10 had the same productAttributeId.

I'm confusing this in my explanation but I'm hoping the image will clarify what I need to do.

This should be simple so I presume I'm missing something.

Comment: More detail: I need to check the combination being submitted against other combinations in the DB, a combination in the DB is defined as one that all the attributeIDs share the same ProductAttributeId.

Comment: What db engine are you using? MySQL, Oracle, MS-SQL...? What programming language is your web application written in?

Comment: Do you mean the combination of AttributedID and ProductAttributeId *together* is unique? Your sentence makes no sense ("So if a user now tried to save an attribute with ID of 1 it will stop them") because you have 2 rows with AttributedID = 1 already. And "if the user chooses a combination of that attribute and another one then they should be allowed to save it." is contradictory.

Comment: Sorry, I'm crap at explaining this without getting overly complex. It's a SQL db by the way and C# is the language.
I need a check to be done before the combination of attribute Ids are saved to verify that exactly that combo doesn't already exist, and the attributeIDs are grouped (if that's the right word) by ProductAttributeID.

Comment: `It's a SQL db by the way` - we know. Which one? Check the tag wiki for the [sql] tag (just hover over it). I'm taking a leap of faith and assuming you meant sql-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question properly, you want to prevent the combination of `AttributeId` and `ProductAttributeId` from being reused.  If that's the case, simply make them a combined primary key, which is by nature `UNIQUE`.

If that's not feasible, create a stored procedure that runs a query against the join for instances of the `AttributeId`.  If the query returns 0 instances, insert the row.

Here's some light code to present the idea (may need to be modified to work with your database):

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM MyJoinTable WHERE AttributeId = @RequestedID
IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO MyJoinTable ...
END
```

Comment: Combined primary key...haven't used that before, might give it a go. It sounds like you've understood my question, which is miraculous as I explained myself so badly (was tired - pondering the question for ages before posting here).

Comment: To add further clarification to my question. Each attributeId or group of attributeIds need to be unique. I can't have attribute Ids (1,10) with the same productAttributeId twice, nor can I have (1,10,34) twice. The productAttributeID is the 'group' to which each bunch of attributeIds belongs so I need to check each time : 'Does a group of these attributeIds already exist, if so stop the save and tell the user they can't save them.'

Comment: You may be making this overcomplicated.  Let me see if I understand.  If you have a `ProductAttributeId` with `AttributeId`s 1 and 10, and you have another `ProductAttributeId` with only one `AttributeId` of 1, is this allowed?  Or are 1 and 10 not allowed ever again, either separate or combined?

Comment: I think I already know the answer, yes it is allowed.  If that's the case, you should be using some sort of bit storage for the attributes, e.g. attribute 1 has a value of 1, 2 has a value of 2, 3 has a value of 4, etc., and store the resultant value.  That way, each combination will create a unique value, and you would just make that column `UNIQUE`.  You wouldn't need to use a combined primary key for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can control your inserts via a stored procedure.  My understanding is that

1. users can select a combination of Attributes, such as

   - just 1
   - 1 and 10 together
   - 1,4,5,10 (4 attributes)

These need to enter the table as a single "batch" against a (new?) productAttributeId

So if (1,10) was chosen, this needs to be blocked because 1-2 and 10-2 already exist.

#### What I suggest

The stored procedure should take the attributes as a single list, e.g. '1,2,3' (comma separated, no spaces, just integers)

You can then use a string splitting UDF or an inline XML trick (as shown below) to break it into rows of a derived table.

Test table

```
create table attrib (attributeid int, productattributeid int)
insert attrib select 1,1
insert attrib select 1,2
insert attrib select 10,2
```

Here I use a variable, but you can incorporate as a SP input param

```
declare @t nvarchar(max) set @t = '1,2,10'

select top(1)
  t.productattributeid,
  count(t.productattributeid) count_attrib,
  count(*) over () count_input
from (select convert(xml,'<a>' + replace(@t,',','</a><a>') + '</a>') x) x
cross apply x.x.nodes('a') n(c)
cross apply (select n.c.value('.','int')) a(attributeid)
left join attrib t on t.attributeid = a.attributeid
group by t.productattributeid
order by countrows desc
```

Output

```
productattributeid     count_attrib     count_input
2                      2                3
```

1. The 1st column gives you the productattributeid that has the most matches
2. The 2nd column gives you how many attributes were matched using the same productattributeid
3. The 3rd column is how many attributes exist in the input

If you compare the last 2 columns and the counts

1. match - you can use the productattributeid to attach to the product which has all these attributes
2. don't match - then you need to do an insert to create a new combination