# PHP - What's this code doing exactly?

Tags: php

I can't figure out how to log into my account here on Stackoverflow, I find it a little confusing. Anyway, I've asked a question here about a problem I'm having:

[Other Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5050727/sql-query-select-from-table-and-group-on-other-column)

I've since found an open source project that does exactly what I need done but the code is PHP and while I can understand most of it there are bits I don't get. I'll post it here with my comments through it and if someone can add extra details that would be appreciated.

```
    public function productAttributeExists($attributesList, $currentProductAttribute = false)
{
    $result = Db::getInstance()->ExecuteS('SELECT pac.`id_attribute`, pac.`id_product_attribute`
    FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'product_attribute` pa
    LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'product_attribute_combination` pac ON (pac.`id_product_attribute` = pa.`id_product_attribute`)
    WHERE pa.`id_product` = '.intval($this->id));

    if (!$result OR empty($result))
        return false;

    $productAttributes = array();
    foreach ($result AS $productAttribute)
        $productAttributes[$productAttribute['id_product_attribute']][] = $productAttribute['id_attribute'];

    foreach ($productAttributes AS $key => $productAttribute)
        if (sizeof($productAttribute) == sizeof($attributesList))
        {
            $diff = false;
            for ($i = 0; $diff == false AND isset($productAttribute[$i]); $i++)
                if (!in_array($productAttribute[$i], $attributesList) OR $key == $currentProductAttribute)
                    $diff = true;
            if (!$diff)
                return true;
        }
    return false;
}
```

Ok turns out I can't comment this code in Stackoverflow without it all going to formatting hell. So my understanding is this:

1) Get the Data
2) If the dataset is empty return false
3) New array called productAttributes
4) Loop through the dataset and populate the array
5) Not sure what this last section is doing, the section beginning 'foreach' is unclear to me.

Any tips appreciated. Incidentally, C# is my preferred language and the one I understand best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function, as it is named, is only supposed to check if a particular attribute list of a product exists and is the same as the one provided in the first parameter.

The last part is confusing, but it's iterating through all the attributes to see if any of the retrieved attributes are the same as the ones provided.

in a loop iteration:

- it first tries to see if the provided attribute list is the same length as the one coming from the database - if not, it just goes to the next attribute list in the for loop
- if the length of the lists is the same, then it will go through each attribute in the attribute list and see if there's something different amongst any of the elements.

The function isn't very optimal, btw.

Comment: Thanks, that was the gist of what I understood as well. Out of interest, in PHP the dollar sign is what you start variable declarations with, is that correct?

Also, this line "foreach ($productAttributes AS $key => $productAttribute)
"   how does that translate to pseudocode / c#? Thanks!

Comment: correct.

PHP has this special type of array called a associative array, which is basically a named hashmap. foreach loops through each element in an array and the variable $key gets the value of the current element's hash (or index) and $value is the value of the current element

you can also use foreach on a regular numerically-indexed array.

Comment: Cool, very clear explanation thanks. Sorry to bother you again (or anyone else who wants to answer) but this line:

foreach ($result AS $productAttribute)
        $productAttributes[$productAttribute['id_product_attribute']][] = $productAttribute['id_attribute'];

Is that multidimensional array being populated?

Comment: yes, exactly. It builds an array holding arrays of product attribute IDs, referenced by the ID of the attribute list. You're not bothering at all.

Comment: Excellent, it's making a lot more sense now. One thing that puzzles me is how the array of productAttributeIds are being grouped, so to speak. By this I mean the query returns a list of productAttributeIds and attributeIds, a foreach goes through each of these and somehow knows to add all similar productattributeIds to one side of the multidimensional array and the corresponding attributeId to the other side of the array. It's confusing as I don't see any kind of where clause to dictate that grouping of the productattributeIds.

Comment: Well, I think the main problem lies in the naming of the variables in the code and database. A productAttributeId in this code is referring to the ID of a row in the database that groups a productAttribute to a certain product. So in essence a product can have many productAttributes and other products can have the same productAttribute. the grouping in the array, into the a form of productAttributes[by-product-attribute-id] -- it would actually be more clear to call the product_attribute_id a product_attribute_set_id - and refer to those as sets.

Comment: To clarify: the naming of the field, product_attribute_id is referring to the relationship: "linking a product to an attribute list" - and that linkage is stored in a separate table and the ID of the primary key of that row is called id - so in the code the author decided to call the ID field product_attribute_id.